# React router displaying content at root route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React router for a SPA, but I'm not sure how to display some content on the index route "/".

My top level router configuration is just:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    // ...
</Route>
```

The top level component renders the header/footer and other common elements:

```
<nav>
    // ...
</nav>

{children}

<nav className="footer">
    // ...
</nav>
```

Child routes are working fine, and they render within the *App* component. However, how do I render some content at the root route so it's not just a blank page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the content you would like to serve for the root route in `<App>` is `<Home>`, below is referenced from the [guide](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md#index-routes) of `react-route`.

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    <Route path="accounts" component={Accounts}/>
    <Route path="statements" component={Statements}/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

And this is what `<App>` might look like.

```
const App = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return {this.props.children || <Home/>};
    }
});
```